# Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, wordpress, security, warnings

I'm using a `WordPress` site, recently I had to update my site to `WordPress 4.6.2`. And now I'm experiencing an error. Can anyone help me out with this? check out the image for the error message:

> Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php
>   on line 270
>
> Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php
>   on line 274
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php:270)
>   in
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tawkto-live-chat/tawkto.php
>   on line 44
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php:270)
>   in
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tawkto-live-chat/tawkto.php
>   on line 44
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php:270)
>   in /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174

Comment: Note that it's **not** due to your update to WP 4.6.2 (which is old, by the way, current version is 4.7+).  It's due to an update to the plugin you are using, OR due to a change in your host provider's policies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect, this question could be handled by reading the error messages carefully. The people who developed PHP went to a lot of trouble to make their messages informative.

The first two error messages in your question tell the story. They're pretty much the same fault.

> Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php on line 270

Let's parse this message.

- `base64_decode`    is a php function. Type `php base64_decode` into your fav search engine to learn more.
- `base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons` is the error message. Try typing that into a search engine to learn more.
- `in /home/play2daa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/PostmanOptions.php on line 270` tells you where the problem occurred. Look! it says `.../plugins/postman-smtp/...` in the path name!  It seems likely you have a WordPress plugin called `Postman SMTP` or maybe `Postman` in your WP install. Have you contacted that plugin's developer to figure out what to do?

Here's the thing: Lots of cybercriminals have figured out how to trick various WordPress plugins into running malicious code by concealing it in base-64 encoded text and uploading it. So, some cheap and nasty hosting services have blocked the PHP call that decodes that kind of text, in an attempt to slow down those miscreants.

You can fix this problem by....

1. getting the plugin developer to issue an update, or repairing the plugin yourself if you're a developer.
2. finding a different plugin to send email from your site.
3. getting your hosting service to re-enable this disabled function.
4. firing your hosting service and getting a new one.

Comment: Excellent advise, in the correct order of priority in my opinion as well.  Very, very good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help...  I appreciate it